# How to access returned html?

Tags: javascript, function, object, closures

Let's say I have a HomeComponent object that has a function which renders html, and the returned value is passed to a spa router dom element, example:

```
const HomeComponent = {
  render: () => {
    return `
    <div>Hello</div>
    <button class="btn">Click</button>
    `;
  }
}
```

How do I access the `button`? Maybe attach an eventlistener to it, for instance, outside the `HomeComponent` object. I also might need to export the `HomeComponent` and interact with it outside it's file.

When I try to console log something from the object.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('button')); // null
```

Comment: you are just returning string to do anything with it content you ned to instantiate dom elements with it...

Comment: Sorry, but this is kind of unclear to me, would you like to give some examples?

Comment: `'<div></div>'` this is string and `document.createElement('div')` this is dom element if you want to interact with divs and buttons you need to create them from dom elements

Comment: you can try using this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-vanilla